# Parameterized build Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

I have configured a job in Jenkins and checked "This build is parameterized" option. The parameter name I have given is "My_Param". The Jenkins is installed in the server machine. So I access the Jenkins dashboard through `http://<servername>:8080/` In the Build part, I have to call a script by opening cygwin. So I write

```
#!C:\cygwin\bin\bash --login -i
./build/myscript.sh -full
```

After the build is completed, I want to move the files to another new directory prefix with Output, This directory name is the parameter I intend to pass. so I write

```
mkdir /cygdrive/c/users/admin/Ouput$My_Param
```

I run the build and pass param as **first**
But, the directory is created as **Output** in the server machine and not as **Outputfirst**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you noted you use cygwin, I understand the server is on windows.

Try parameter windows style environment variable: **%My_Param%** or linux: **${My_Param}**

I hope this helps.